# Getting a zsh alias including a pipe to execute

Tags: macos, command-line, alias, zsh, zshrc

I wanted a command that would quickly copy the current `tmux` window layout to the clipboard on Mac using `zsh`. I came up with the following:

```
tmux list-windows | awk '{print $7}' |  sed 's/\]$//' | pbcopy
```

When I run this from the command line it works perfectly with an output like the following:

```
d97b,135x32,0,0[135x16,0,0{87x16,0,0,0,47x16,88,0,1},135x15,0,17{87x15,0,17,2,47x15,88,17,3}]
```

However, I can't seem to run it as an alias. If I add the line:

```
alias layout="tmux list-windows | awk '{print $7}' |  sed 's/\]$//' | pbcopy"
```

to my `.zshrc` file when I run `layout` the command does not work as expected. It instead outputs the full `tmux list-windows` command with the word `layout` replacing the session name:

```
0: layout* (4 panes) [135x32] [layout d97b,135x32,0,0[135x16,0,0{87x16,0,0,0,47x16,88,0,1},135x15,0,17{87x15,0,17,2,47x15,88,17,3}]] @0 (active)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your '$7' interpreted during the .zshrc loading ? Couldn't it be the issue ?

Answer (score 6):

**alex_i** is correct, if you escape the `$7` everything works.

`alias layout="tmux list-windows | awk '{print \$7}' |  sed 's/\]$//' | pbcopy"`

Note the backslash before the $7.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use an alias; use a function:

```
layout () {
    tmux list-windows | awk '{print $7}' | sed 's/\]$//' | pbcopy
}
```

Then you don't need to worry about quoting.

Comment: That's a really good method. Hadn't looked into zsh functions before - they're really useful!